# How can i update the reference of and activity in a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I  have a thread that is running and making requests to the server and according to the response from the server I change color of several elements in the app. The problem is: I need to change activity and the thread has to keep running to make requests in this new activity but when I come to the main activity where i need to color those elements again it won't paint them. I know it's because when the thread is first created in the main activity it has one reference to that main activity that keeps within the threat and when i leave the activity it destroys it and then when i come back the reference is new but the reference of the activity that i'm working on the thread it's the old one, beucase I tested in debug mode and found out that.

The code of the thread is this one:

```
    public void initiateThreads(final boolean fromDisplayThread){


            if(!fromDisplay){
            t1= new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    final Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {


                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            String url = "XX.XX.XX.XX";

                            Log.i("DREG", "onLoadMoreItems: " + url);

                            final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                                            System.out.println(response);
                                            text.setText(response);

                                            try {

                                                JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
                                                String FRONT = res.getString("FRONT");
                                                String BACK= res.getString("BACK");
                                                String LEFT = res.getString("LEFT");
                                                String RIGHT = res.getString("RIGHT");

                                                setWarningLevel(FRONT, BACK, LEFT, RIGHT);

                                                setDelay();

                                                visualWarning(FRONT, BACK, LEFT, RIGHT);
                                            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                                                text.setText(e);
                                                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                                .show();
                                                    }
                                                });

                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                                            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                                            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                        "Oops. Timeout error!",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                text.setText(error);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            );
                            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                    10000,
                                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                        }
                    }, 0, 2000);

                }
            });
            t1.start();
}
```

And the function that paint the elements is the `visualWarning()` and the code is:

```
 public void visualWarning(String FRONT, String BACK, String LEFT, String RIGHT){


            switch (FRONT) {//FRONT
            case "NONE":
                ImageView imageViewIcon1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageViewIcon1.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#0000D3"));

                ImageView imageViewIcon2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                imageViewIcon2.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#0000D3"));

                ImageView imageViewIcon3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                imageViewIcon3.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#0000D3"));

                ImageView imageViewIcon4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                imageViewIcon4.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#0000D3"));


//SWITCH STAEMENT CONTINUES BUT IT'S ALL THE SAME JUST CHANGING COLOR

}
```

How can i update the activity currently running inside the thread?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally bad to keep reference to an activity in a background thread. What you need is events, you can use LocalBroadcasts, send a broadcast to your activity whenever you receive data from server, you will receive broadcasts in the activity which is running.

Make sure to unregister the broadcast in onDestroy of the activity

Answer (score 0):

Use [`runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) to execute your portion of code on main thread

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        ....
        runOnUiThread(() -> visualWarning(FRONT, BACK, LEFT, RIGHT));
    }
}
```